# Open an existing excel file and writing a new line in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've searched through some old answers about my problem, but couldn't find an answer.

The problem: I want to open an existing Excel file, than write a new-line with a list and than save the current Excel-File.

My current code is:

import pandas

```
import pandas as pd
l_bsp = range(1,13)
df = pd.read_excel("Existing_file.xlsx")
df.loc[df.shape[0]+1] = l_bsp
print(df)
```

Right now it only changes my Dataframe without changing the Excel File. How to I add the list into the existing excel file?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to write it back. by e.g. [`df.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code only read the Excel file without writing it back.  You can use command such as [`df.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).    For better understanding of the writing process, suggest you also take a look at the pandas user guide on [Writing Excel files](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#writing-excel-files)